# may be python error!

Tags: python, linux

Hi
I'm not familiar with python, I just want to check something so I tried to run a .py code in linux  so I wrote :

```
./waf wifi-olsr-flowmon --plot
```

which is a .py program after that whatever I want to run just see these error:

```
/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/wscript: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/.waf-1.5.16-e6d03192b5ddfa5ef2c8d65308e48e42/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 197, in load_module
    exec(compile(code,file_path,'exec'),module.__dict__)
  File "/home/bahar/Desktop/ns/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-allinone-3.9/ns-3.9/wscript", line 32, in <module>
    import cflags # override the build profiles from waf
ImportError: No module named cflags
```

I dont know what does it mean or why it happened, would you please tell me what is the problem .
may be I should add this note that even now that I don't want to run any .py code and just wana run .cc I can't do it and see this error always

```
 Bests
```

Comment: How did you install ns3? Did you follow the steps here: http://groups.google.com/group/ns-3-users/web/installing-ns3-on-ubuntu?pli=1

Comment: no I just follow the tutorial and did as same as what I did before about ns3.8

Comment: It didn't have any problem till now please tell me how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Python was unable to locate a module named `cflags`, but the code you're running tries to import it. Perhaps you need to set PYTHONPATH, or install the `cflags` module.

(Also, paragraphs are your friend.)

Comment: would you please tell me how to do this